# Mostrar datos en un modal con bootstrap-laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap, laravel-blade, laravel-6

estoy tratando de mostrar información por medio de un modal pero solo me aparece la info del ultimo agregado abriéndolo desde cualquier botón.

Tambien he intentado haciéndolo todo con el método show del controlador y importandolo con @include en el 
modal-body pero no me funciona

no pongo lo del show porque de pronto los confundo pero si quieren ver el código me dicen y lo monto

por ejemplo en el unico campo que puse en el modal me aparece el ultimo que tengo en la base de datos mas no el seleccionado

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<section class="container mt-2">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h4> Solicitudes de diligencias para procesos contratados </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                            <thead>
                              <th>Proceso</th>
                              <th>Servicio</th>
                              <th>Dependiente</th>
                              <th>Estado</th>
                              <th>Ver</th>
                              <th>Cambiar de estado</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                              @foreach ($diligences as $diligence)
                                <tr>
                                  <td>{{ $diligence->process->name }}</td>
                                  <td>{{ $diligence->service->name }}</td>
                                  <td>{{ $diligence->process->dependant->name }}</td>
                                  <td>{{ $diligence->status }}</td>
                                  <td>
                                    <a class="btn btn-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                                      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                    </a>
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ url('show/'.$diligence->id) }}">
                                      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                    </a>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {{-- Modal de editar perfil --}}

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Editar Perfil</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  {{-- @include('diligencias.show', ['diligencia' => $diligence]) --}}
                  <div>
                    <label for="name">Nombre del proceso</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" readonly value="{{ $diligence->process->name }}">                    
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
@endsection
```

Controlador

```
public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        $services = Service::all();
        $processes = Process::all();
        $diligences = Diligence::all()->where('status', 'pendiente');
        return view('diligencias.index', compact('diligences', 'processes', 'services'));
    }
```

este es el show del controlador

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $users = User::all();
        $services = Service::all();
        $diligences = Diligence::find($id);
        $processes = Process::find($id);
        return view('diligencias.show', compact('processes', 'diligences'));
    }
```

Comment: Tu tarea debe incluir javascript para crear dinamisco y reutilizando el mismo modal, o bien, deberas crear dentro del foreach un modal por cada elemento, lo cual hara el sitio muy pesado

Comment: como podria hacerlo con js?

Comment: Tendrias que agregar el codigo de `diligencias.show`

Comment: ya lo subí bro.

Comment: Me refiero al blade `show`

Comment: ah, es solamente unos inputs como el que están en el modal, es exactamente igual

Comment: si quieres mostrar el modal desde un button puedes enviar el id por medio de ajax o fetch, e invocar por medio de una ruta el metodo show, enviar la data en json y pintarla en tu modal, alli no sera necesario recorrer con un loop la data pues solo te va traer la info de diligences asociada a ese id pero obviamente debes utilizar js